# A view mode to only show the askers or the answerers on the question list

Tags: feature-request, moderation, question-lists

When I search through question lists (whatever type of list they may be) sometimes I want to see who the asker (or the answerer) is before delving into it. The current view policy makes this impossible because it shows the user performing the latest action.

Can we have a view mode selection option which makes it possible to select between the classic, the asker, and the answerer for question (or for answer lists depending on the type of the list being browsed) lists?

Comment: You can see who asked only in the [Newest Questions](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions?sort=newest). For answers, you can search for answers only, then again sort by newest: http://meta.stackexchange.com/search?tab=newest&q=is%3aa

Comment: @ShadowWizard That's solves the 'asker' issue to some point but what about the answerers.

Comment: I would also have the view options on search results. For example if I select the "Newest" mode on this search query I don't see only the 'askers': http://meta.stackexchange.com/search?tab=newest&q=request

Comment: Not really clear what you want to see as the answerer in a questions list. You want to see the last user who actually posted an answer?

Comment: As for newest mode and askers in search, you have to add the `is:q` operator: http://meta.stackexchange.com/search?tab=newest&q=request%20is%3aq

Comment: Yes I would like to see the last user who posted an answer for a specific search query result. (If there's one. If there isn't any answers than again the view mode should switch to a default setting like the 'asker' or the classic mode)

Comment: @ShadowWizard The *is:q* operator filters out the answers from the search query results.

Answer (score 2):

I don't see the actual value of disclosing the author of a post on the frontpage. Why would you be more interested in the posts of user A than user B? Just because his name is Jon Skeet?

Adding additional modes to show the various authors defeats the purpose of the question list: it is not about the user, it is about the post. The current toggle modes allow exactly that, and nothing more.

Comment: I'm not especially interested in the person but about their reputation. It can tell you to a degree if the question is asked (or answered) by someone new or old on the site.